# Compiler error LKN2019: Unresolved external symbol when dealing with inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, linker, compiler-errors

I have the following Files in C++:

Object.h:

```
class Object{
    public:
        Object(void);
        ~Object(void);

        GLfloat getLeft();
        GLfloat getRight();
        GLfloat getBottom();
        GLfloat getTop();
};
```

Player.h:

```
    class Player : public Object{
    public:
        Player(void);
        ~Player(void);

        GLfloat getLeft();
        GLfloat getRight();
        GLfloat getBottom();
        GLfloat getTop();
};
```

Platform.h:

```
class Platform : public Object{
public:
    Platform(void);
    ~Platform(void);

    GLfloat getLeft();
    GLfloat getRight();
    GLfloat getBottom();
    GLfloat getTop();
};
```

Pillar.h:

```
class Pillar : public Object{
public:
    Pillar(void);
    ~Pillar(void);

    GLfloat getLeft();
    GLfloat getRight();
    GLfloat getBottom();
    GLfloat getTop();
};
```

Collision.h:

```
#include "Player.h"
#include "Platform.h"
#include "Pillar.h"

class Collision
{
public:
    Collision(void);
    ~Collision(void);
    bool CollisionDetect(Object* obj1, Object* obj2);
};
```

Collision.cpp:

```
bool Collision::CollisionDetect(Object* obj1, Object* obj2){
    return !(obj2->getLeft() > obj1->getRight()
        || obj2->getRight() < obj1->getLeft()
        || obj2->getTop() > obj1->getBottom()
        || obj2->getBottom() < obj1->getTop());
}
```

CollisionDetect will be comparing whether 2 different Objects have collided and to do this I need specific x and y values however, the types of object may vary depending on different circumstances, and each type of object will have different ways to find their x and y values. This means that I have had to re-define the relevant get Methods in their subclasses, but when I run this code I end up with the errors:

```
1>Collision.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Object::getLeft(void)" (?getLeft@Object@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Collision::CollisionDetect(class Object *,class Object *)" (?CollisionDetect@Collision@@QAE_NPAVObject@@0@Z)
1>Collision.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Object::getRight(void)" (?getRight@Object@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Collision::CollisionDetect(class Object *,class Object *)" (?CollisionDetect@Collision@@QAE_NPAVObject@@0@Z)
1>Collision.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Object::getBottom(void)" (?getBottom@Object@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Collision::CollisionDetect(class Object *,class Object *)" (?CollisionDetect@Collision@@QAE_NPAVObject@@0@Z)
1>Collision.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: float __thiscall Object::getTop(void)" (?getTop@Object@@QAEMXZ) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Collision::CollisionDetect(class Object *,class Object *)" (?CollisionDetect@Collision@@QAE_NPAVObject@@0@Z)
1>C:\Users\Student\Dropbox\Work\Year 2\Graphics 1\Coursework\GraphicsCoursework\Debug\GraphicsCoursework.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals
```

Is it a problem with my inheritance that is causing this, or is it something else?

Answer (score 1):

Exactly make the 4 functions in the object class "virtual"
Infact i would suggest make it pure virtual,

```
class Object{
    public:
        Object(void);
        ~Object(void);

        virtual GLfloat getLeft() = 0;
        virtual GLfloat getRight() = 0;
        virtual GLfloat getBottom() = 0;
        virtual GLfloat getTop() = 0;
};
```

This will force you to override those four function in the derived class, and provide a definition..

Answer (score 0):

Each of your classes, Derived as well as Base need to **define** those 4 member functions.
Only pure virtual functions in C++ are allowed to exist without a definition.

Also, the redeclaration and definition of these 4 member functions in derived classes **[HIDE](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/hiding-rule.html)** the functions in the Base class.      From your usage it seems you want to use dynamic polymorphism through **function overidding** and for that you need to use the keyword `virtual`.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you need `virtual` functions.

```
class Object{
    public:
        Object(void);
        ~Object(void);

        virtual GLfloat getLeft()=0;
        virtual GLfloat getRight()=0;
        virtual GLfloat getBottom()=0;
        virtual GLfloat getTop()=0;
};
```